# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] while inserting a token

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a social media (social network), and right now im trying to use tokens to do the login, but I keep having the error above. 
My code ran perfectly without the "token code". The error seems coming from inserting the token in database, but when I check the database the token was inserted correctly... 
Here's the code,and the full error message

(**Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\DB.php:15 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\DB.php(15): PDOStatement->fetchAll() #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\login.php(18): DB::query('INSERT INTO tok...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\DB.php on line 15**)

Login.php

```
<?php
//session_start();
include_once('DB.php');

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $password =$_POST['password'];


   if (DB::query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email', array(':email' => $email)))
   {
         if (password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$email))[0]['password'])) 
         {
            $cstrong = TRUE;
            $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64,$cstrong));
            $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id from users where email=:email', array(':email' => $email))[0]['id'];
            DB::query('INSERT INTO tokens VALUES (\'\',:token,:user_id)',array(':token'=>sha1($token),':user_id'=>$user_id));
            header('location: ');

           setcookie("SNID",$token, time() + 60*60*24*7, '/',NULL,NULL,TRUE);
         }
   }

      else
      {
         header('location: index.html');
      }
}
```

DB.php

```
<?php 
class DB
{
    private static function connect()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pap;charset=utf8','root','');
        $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query,$params=array())
    {
        $statement = self::connect() ->prepare($query);
        $statement ->execute($params);
        $data = $statement -> fetchALL();
        return $data;



    }
}



?>
```

I hope you guys can help me out... Im still a learner so every help is welcome!

Comment: Your `query()` function always does a `fetchALL()` when running any query.  As an INSERT doesn't have a result set, this isn't going to work.

Comment: @aynber that doesnt answer my question.. It would work if I didnt have a login page, if I dont have that line of code ```$data = $statement -> fetchALL();
  return $data; ```, I cant log in

Comment: @NigelRen so how can I do this? if I take out that statements I cant log in

Comment: Sure it does. fetchAll does not work with Insert/Update/Delete, but you're attempting to use it for all queries. Break out the functions, one for select, one for everything else (possibly), and only use the fetchAll in the Select function.

Comment: I think the *best* solution would be to have a specific version of `query()`, which is used for INSERT statements.

Comment: @aynber Already tried ```if(explode(' ', $query) == 'SELECT') ``` but it didnt worked

Comment: @NigelRen I probably dont know how to do that, do you have some kind of manual or a link to something about that?

Comment: Explode returns an array, that won't work. You need to create specific functions for each type of query instead of using one catch-all function.

Comment: @aynber How can I do that? I'm not finding correct syntax or answer to that

Comment: @NigelRen someone?

Comment: @NigelRen I'm still a learner, so  could I use some help please since my post is taken down?

Comment: @aynber please??